# Want to show sub category in magento

Tags: php, magento, categories

I want to show sub sub categories in my magento static block.

For example there is Women category on that page. I want to show all subcategories of women, and the sub categorie of this.

Structure on women page will be

```
Category 1 -> sub 1 -> Sub 1
```

I have already implemented some code but it dont show sub categories:

```
<?php 
//If there are sub categories
$categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories();
$categoriescount = $this->getCurrentChildCategories()->count();
if ($categoriescount > 0): 
?>
<div class="sub-category-container">    
    <?php 
    //Loop through categories
    foreach ($categories as $category):
    ?>
    <div class="sub-category">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($category)?>" class="cat-image">
        <?php 
        // If there is a thumbnail set for the category - Display it
        if($imgUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getThumbnail()):?>
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()."media/catalog/category/".$imgUrl ?>" width="220" height="110" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
        <div class="inner-sub-category">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($category)?>" class="sub-link"><?php echo $category->getName()?></a>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($category)?>" class="btn"><span>View All</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php else:?>
<p>No Sub Categories</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Output of above code http://prntscr.com/6wcfov

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `getCategories()` method in the Categories model.

```
$subcategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($parentCategory->getId());
foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
    ...do things
}
```

You can do this recursively to get all the subcategories in a parent category.

Comment: Can you please explain how and where to use in detail?

Answer (score 0):

> Display SubCategory of current  category
>
> ```
>     $loadCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCat->getId());
>
> $subCategories = explode(',', $loadCategory->getChildren());
>
> foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId )
> {
>     $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);
>
>     if($cat->getIsActive())
>     {
>         echo '<a href="'.$cat->getURL().'">'.$cat->getName().'</a>';
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: TRY THIS $currentCat= Mage::registry('current_category');  $loadCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCat->getId());   $_subcategories = $loadCategory ->getChildrenCategories();  foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory){ echo $_subcategory->getName();}